# XSLT - Call a template with parameters

Tags: templates, xslt, parameters

Can you help me to better understand this part of the code:

When 'template1' is called, what parameters are sent and with which values? What I understand is that the parameter 'xValue' is sent to template, but I don't understand the `<xsl:param name="xValue" select="0"/>`. Are the two conditions after the template is called to determine the value of the parameter to send?

```
<xsl:call-template name="template1">
    <xsl:with-param name="xValue">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($var1)=1 ">
                 ...
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                 ...
             </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>


<xsl:template name="template1">
    <xsl:param name="xValue" select="0"/>
    <xsl:param name="yValue" select="0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="newValue">
      <xsl:variable name="char" select="substring($xValue,1,1)"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="matches(upper-case($char),'[A-F]')">
          ...
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          ...
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(string-length($xValue) = 1)">
          ...
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
          ...
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand the `<xsl:param name="xValue" select="0"/>`.

This defines "0" as the default value for the xValue parameter. If you call the template with a different value specified explicitly (as you do in your example), the default value is overridden.

> Are the two conditions after the template is called to determine the
>   value of the parameter to send?

Yes. More precisely, there is **one** choose statement that determines the value to be sent; it has one test and two values to choose from, according to the result of the test.

Answer (score 1):

`<xsl:param name="xValue" select="0"/>` is defining a parameter named `xValue` with a default value of `0`.

When you use `<xsl:with-param name="xValue">` in your `xsl:call-template`, you're overriding that default value.